# ngFor Ddisplay null data

Tags: angular, typescript

I got problem `*ngFor` display null data, even though it have a data.This my code as your reference. I don't any idea what wrong with my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card col-8 shadow-sm">
    <div class="list-group">
        <form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.valid && onSubmit()">
        <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start" *ngFor="let list of eventData ; let i of index">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <h5 class="card-title pr-3 d-inline-block font-weight-bold">{{list.eventName}}</h5>
                <span class="border border-danger d-flex align-self-center pl-2 pr-2 text-danger">{{list.seats}} space left</span>
            </span>
                <span class="btn btn-primary btg" (click)="lightbox.open(0, 'lightbox',test)"><i class="fa fa-image pr-2"></i>Gallery</span>
            </div>
                <p class="card-text">
                    {{list.eventNote}}
                </p>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getEvent(this.Id);
}

getEvent(id){
    this.httpService.getConferenceEvent(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.eventData = data['events'];
        console.log(this.eventData)
      })
  }
```

**Service**

```
 public getConferenceEvent(id):Observable<ConfEvent[]>{
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer '+this.getToken()
      })
    };
    return this.httpClient.get<ConfEvent[]>((this.serverUrl + this.basePath + url+id),httpOptions);
  } 

export class ConfEvent {
  eventCategory: string;
  eventName: string;
  eventNote: string;
  seats: string;
  feeList: Array<string>;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure the backend returns the data correctly, you could try to use the `async` pipe with the `*ngIf` directive and avoid the subscription in the component. Try the following

Service

```js
public getConferenceEvent(id):Observable<ConfEvent[]>{
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer '+this.getToken()
    })
  };
  return this.httpClient.get<ConfEvent[]>((this.serverUrl + this.basePath + url+id),httpOptions).pipe(
    map(response => response['events'])
  );
}
```

Controller

```js
eventdata$: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.eventdata$ = this.httpService.getConferenceEvent(this.Id);
}
```

Template

```html
<div *ngIf="(eventdata$ | async) as eventdata" class="card col-8 shadow-sm">
    <div class="list-group">
        <form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.valid && onSubmit()">
        <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start" *ngFor="let list of eventData ; let i of index">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <h5 class="card-title pr-3 d-inline-block font-weight-bold">{{list.eventName}}</h5>
                <span class="border border-danger d-flex align-self-center pl-2 pr-2 text-danger">{{list.seats}} space left</span>
            </span>
                <span class="btn btn-primary btg" (click)="lightbox.open(0, 'lightbox',test)"><i class="fa fa-image pr-2"></i>Gallery</span>
            </div>
                <p class="card-text">
                    {{list.eventNote}}
                </p>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother it really helpfull

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this kind of issue, you should use resolver.

but, to understand your issue, you get data from a service. With subscription you use asynchronism so Angular will continue to execute code and build dom during the time the service is waiting the response. so inside of your you console.log the data, so indeed, your console.log should be filled. BUT when your view is built, your data are probably not arrived since it's asynchronous. You could use the solution proposed by @Michael D with pipe async, or you can just update the reference of your array that will trigger a dom rebuild with the following code

```
getEvent(id){
    this.httpService.getConferenceEvent(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.eventData = data['events'];
        this.eventData = [...this.eventData]
      })
  }
```